# Difference between ‘convinced’ and ‘made it clear’?

Tags: grammar

The White House spokesman made it clear that the time of the election would not be changed.

Can I replace ‘made it clear’ by ‘convinced’?

Comment: Have you checked the definition of "to convince" in a dictionary?

Comment: I saw this sentence: The experts were now fully convinced that the animal was a puma.   So, I felt this sentence can use convinced as well.

Comment: @Cardinal Don't you think you're being a bit unfair, considering this is an SE for *learning* English? We can't expect all questions to be perfectly formed, and I was able to answer the question quite easily. Many things can be solved by correctly using a dictionary, however it is a skill few are properly taught.

Comment: @Y.zeng in relation to your puma sentence, consider who or what is doing the action compared to receiving the action.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot replace "made it clear" with "convinced" in this case.

To **convince** someone of something means to cause them to believe firmly in the truth of something, or to persuade them to do something.

When someone is **convinced** of something, it means they believe firmly that it is true or correct.

When someone **makes** something **clear**, they say something in a way that makes it impossible for there to be any doubt about their meaning, wishes, or intentions.

In this case, after the White House spokesperson has **made** it **clear** that the time of the election will not be changed, the people hearing this announcement might be **convinced** that there will be no change to the time of the election.